# serialize dictionary with dynamic key

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I would like to create a django rest framework serializer, in order to serialize this dict:

```
"series": {
        "real": "Real",
        "forecast": "Forecast",
        "upper_ci": "Upper CI",
        "lower_ci": "Lower CI"
}
```

The problems is that real, forecast, upper_ci, lower_ci are all dynamic keys, and there might be other different keys.

Comment: What are "dynamic keys"? And how do they prevent you from serializing the dict?

Comment: `import pickle` followed by `pickle.dumps(mydictionary)`

Comment: @timgeb with "dynamic keys" i mean that could be "real" or other different name that I can't know before, so I can't define specific  attribute inside serializer class

Comment: A serializer should be able to handle any string key (and many other datatypes) regardless of their specific value. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Hamall: well ho do you know what key to use to extract the forecast? How do you know the "meta data"?

Comment: @Hamall Do you know how many keys can come? Are those keys fixed?

Comment: @rahul.m unfortunatly not, I just know that the "real" key is mandatory but is the only one

Comment: so you can get basically *anything* in the request or input? can you confirm that your API is prepared to handle garbage input?